# Resettable counter using JK flip

Tags: counter, cadence, ripple-counter

[image: pulses to be counted]I want to design a binary counter in Cadence that counts pulses in every consecutive 50 nano seconds but i want it to be reset at the end of each 50 ns and shortly - so that it doesn't miss any pulse - start counting again. What do I need to add to a basic JK flip-flop like this to make the this kind of reset possible?
[image: jkff]

Comment: I suspect an X-Y problem. How big a counter and what do you want to count? What Cadence? Cadence Verilog , Cadence schematic, Cadence analog sim? Also J-K are nice for education and making complex problems for student but real counters are using D-registers with logic, mostly in FPGAs

Comment: @Oldfart I recall making discrete state machines using JK devices ('7476 parts), but that was many years ago (decades in fact).

Comment: I agree with @Oldfart. I was designing chips in the 1980s and we never used anything but D flip-flops. Now I teach and I refuse to talk about JK, Toggle, or any other antique.

Comment: Are the pulses you're counting synchronous or asynchronous with respect to the 50 ns reset pulse?

Comment: @Oldfart Cadence schematics, I want to make a counter with flip flops that are made of gates, and I want to design the gates in schematics using MOSFETs and finally have a binary counter. But I don't know which flip flop is better for such a counter and how can I reset it every 50 ns? I added the pulses picture. please heck

Comment: @DaveTweed the pulses are synchronous. I added the picture. please check

Answer (score -1):

The solution to prevent metastable (race) and clock speed issues is a fast sync prescaler design.  Your specs need to be defined before any design , discrete FF or otherwise IC choice may begin.